# bindParam doesn't work when foreign key constraint set to cascade

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cascade, bindparam

I'm creating a forum site for an assignment and the code worked fine until I changed two things: I changed my database constraints to CASCADE (needs to be like that for the rest of the site) and I changed the query function to prepare, bind and execute for security.

**This code works**

```
$insert_post_query =
"INSERT INTO posts (
    thread_id, user_id, username, post_content, post_date
)
VALUES (
    '$topic_id', '$user_id', '$username', '$post_content', '$post_date'
)";
$post_result = $db->query($insert_post_query);
```

**This code doesn't work**

```
$insert_post_query =
"INSERT INTO posts (
    thread_id, user_id, username, post_content, post_date
)
VALUES (
    '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'
)";
try{
$post_result = $db->prepare($insert_post_query);
$post_result->bindParam(1,$topic_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$post_result->bindParam(2,$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$post_result->bindParam(3,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->bindParam(4,$post_content,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->bindParam(5,$post_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->execute();

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Unable to add the post<br>$e";
    exit;
}
```

**This is the error**

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forum`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `threads` (`thread_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I'm fairly new to PHP so it could be something simple, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `threads` entity with `id` equal to `thread_id` you provide in bindParam?

Comment: Remove apostrophes surrounding query's placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way, before insert data set foreign_key_checks = 0 than active it again with same query line with value 1.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

$insert_post_query =
"INSERT INTO posts (
    thread_id, user_id, username, post_content, post_date
)
VALUES (
    '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'
)";
try{
$post_result = $db->prepare("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");
$post_result = $db->prepare($insert_post_query);
$post_result->bindParam(1,$topic_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$post_result->bindParam(2,$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$post_result->bindParam(3,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->bindParam(4,$post_content,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->bindParam(5,$post_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$post_result->execute();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Unable to add the post<br>$e";
    exit;
}
$post_result = $db->prepare("SET foreign_key_checks = 1");
```